# Map multiple native events to a semantic application event in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have not used Ember.js before, but after reading the part of the  [guide on views](http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/#toc_event-bubbling), I wanted to know how the Ember experts out there would handle a situation where multiple native events needed to be mapped to the same "application event".

In the guide, the example given shows mapping the (native) click event to the (application-specific) deleteItem event.  In many cases, it is common for many native events to map to one application-specific event.  What if a user was using a touch device that also had a keyboard and mouse attached (e.g. soon-to-come Windows 8 tablets), and I needed to map the "touchstart", "click" and "keyup" (e.g. `[CTRL]-D`) events to the same application-specific event like deleteItem?

Would you just put 3 methods on the view -- touchStart, click and KeyUp -- and have them all call a common 4th method to send the deleteItem event?

Is there anything built into Ember to handle this situation -- specifically, the situation where multiple native events all have the same semantic meaning in an app?  I think this will become more and more common as browsers are touch enabled, laptops are touch-enabled and browser APIs can accept input from other hardware like mic, camera, etc... I could imagine a device where 5 or 6 native events all have the same semantic meaning for a given view.

Thanks!

Comment: I would think minimally you would want to use the same handler for all callbacks accomplishing the same task. In some cases it may behoove you to separate the duties into different handlers, but in general I would share the same handler among all of the events with the same requirement.

Comment: Right, that is how I would handle it -- I was just wondering if some optimizations and/or general techniques for reducing repetitive code have been built into Ember for this...

Answer (score 2):

We've been talking about something similar to support 'tap' events.

I think the best approach is to use register jQuery 'special events'. Here's a link to more information: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/

To make a special event work with Ember views, you'll need to register it as a custom event on your `Ember.Application` instance:

```
Ember.Application.create({
  customEvents: {
    // key is the jquery event, value is the name used in views
    myeventname: 'myEventName'
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain more? Maybe a simple code example would make it clear how this works.